# Multiple Kile instances with multiple Okular instances

Tags: editors, kile, okular

I usually worked with a unique instance of the latex editor `Kile`, together with the `ForwardPDF` build to see the output with forward search in a unique instance of `Okular` (this uses `okular --unique`).

I would now like to use multiple instances of `Kile` (using `kile --new`), each having its own instance of `Okular`.

When simply running multiple instances of `Kile`, they all share the same Okular instance, so when using `ForwardPDF` on both `Kile` instances, then one `Kile` instance jumps into the `Okular` instance of the other `Kile` instance, and vice versa. Secondly, and maybe even more annoying, is that the backwards search indeed jumps into the wrong instance of `Kile`, making the multiple instances impossible to use...

Any ideas how to get each of them its own `Okular` instance?